# i'm new to flutter please how can i use named parameters here

Tags: dart

In my function of addFruit(), I want to use named parameters. Check the commented part.

```
class AddFruit extends StatelessWidget {
  final String color;
  AddFruit( this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Fruit');
    Future<void> addFruit() {
      return users
          .add({
        //'name': "orange",
      })
          .then((value) => print("fruit Added"))
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add fruit: $error"));
    }

    return Scaffold(..)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more things about firebase in [document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

get fruitCollection => FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Fruit');

class AddFruit extends StatefulWidget {
  AddFruit({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddFruit> createState() => _AddFruitState();
}

class _AddFruitState extends State<AddFruit> {
  Future<void> addFruit() {
    name = nameController.text;
    if (name.isEmpty) {
      return Future.value(null);
    } else {
      nameTextField.clear();
      return fruitCollection
          .add({
            'name': name,
          })
          .then((value) => print("fruit Added"))
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add fruit: $error"));
    }
  }

  var nameTextField = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: nameTextField,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: addFruit, child: const Text("save")),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView(
              children: const [ListTile()],
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```